# Facebook login is failing when Facebook app is installed on iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, facebook

I am suffering with Facebook login issue. If there is no Facebook app is installed on iPhone then my opens Facebook login on browser and it's working fine after reinstallation of my app but If I install Facebook app on my iPhone and test Facebook login it's goes through my app and it's working fine if it is first time login. After login with Facebook if I am deleting my app and reinstall it then it is not opening login page and I am getting an error - "Invalid sso_key parameter.  The key com.boxscoregames.S1 does not match any allowed allowed bundle IDs.  Configure your iOS bundle ID at http://developers.facebook.com/apps/265799363556746"

Here is my code for Facebook login -

```
-(void)loginViewShowingLoggedInUser:(FBLoginView *)loginView
{
  NSLog (@"You are logged in.");
}
-(void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user
{
   NSLog(@"%@",user);
   globalUserName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"fb%@",[user objectForKey:@"id"]];
   globalEmail = [user objectForKey:@"email"];
   globalUserId = [user objectForKey:@"id"];
   globalFirstName = [user objectForKey:@"first_name"];
   globalLastName = [user objectForKey:@"last_name"];
   globalProfilePic = user.objectID;
   fbAccessToken = [[[FBSession activeSession]accessTokenData]accessToken];
   hud = [appDel indicator];
   [self.view addSubview:hud];

   BOOL internetBool = [appDel isInternetReachable];
   if (internetBool) {
    NSLog(@"Internet is there");
    [hud show:YES];
    [self fbLoginWebService];    }
  else
  {
    [self showAlertWithMessage:@"No network connection. Please try again."];
  }
}
-(void)loginViewShowingLoggedOutUser:(FBLoginView *)loginView
{}
-(void)loginView:(FBLoginView *)loginView handleError:(NSError *)error
 {
    NSLog(@"%@",[error localizedDescription]);
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

I know I am late but someone may find it helpful. 
As Ming Li said You have problems with your bundle id . You must change it to your Xcode's bundle ID . The two id's must match . The easiest way is to follow quickStart guide line in https://developers.facebook.com/quickstarts/  and in  the section "supply us with your Bundle Identifier" just copy and paste your Xcode bundle ID. 
It worked for me.

Comment: Thank you, this helped me out as well!

Answer (score 0):

Did you go to that URL? If so, you'll see that the bundle ID configured there is not com.boxscoregames.S1, which is why SSO is failing for you.

If com.boxscoregames.S1 is your bundle ID, then you should add that there in the iOS section for https://developers.facebook.com/apps/265799363556746/settings/

Comment: But it's working fine if it is going through browser.

Comment: That's because the browser is not capable of checking the calling app's bundle ID.

Comment: I solved the problem using this code "_loginButton.loginBehavior = FBSessionLoginBehaviorForcingSafari;". Thank you very much for response.

Comment: Please do not do that. It's a much worse user experience for people who actually have the FB app installed (it will go to Safari, where they likely won't be logged into Facebook, and will be forced to login there). Just fix your bundle ID in your app. There will be other issues using the SDK if you don't fix your bundle ID anyways.